# Pulling out variables through the integral sign sometimes it's okay sometimes it's not okay

Tags: calculus, integration

clearly a bad idea to do this.. $$\int 4yx^3dx = yx^4$$ ..plus possibly a constant or a function of y... specially bad, for example, if $y$ happened to be $y=x^3$ or any non constant function of $x$ for that matter.. thus for many reasons this  seems like a bad idea.. 
YET... we [some of us] do exactly this when we do something such as $$\int\int_R 4yx^3dA =\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\int_{a_y}^{b_y} 4yx^3dxdy =\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\color{blue}{\left(\int_{a_y}^{b_y} 4yx^3dx\right)}dy $$

$$ =\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\color{blue}{\left. yx^4\right|_{a_Y}^{b_y}}dy $$

seems troubling to me that we use the same notation to mean two different things..

would it be safer to say that $$\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\int_{a_y}^{b_y} 4yx^3dxdy= \int_{c_1}^{c_2}\color{blue}{\left(\int_{a_y}^{b_y} 4yx^3\partial x\right)}dy$$ rather than the contradicting and commonly used statement

$$\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\int_{a_y}^{b_y} 4yx^3dxdy= \int_{c_1}^{c_2}\color{blue}{\left(\int_{a_y}^{b_y} 4yx^3dx\right)}dy$$

perhaps i am missing something,   any help would be greatly appreciated. 
thx.

Comment: Do you want to just solve $$\int 4yx^3dx = yx^4$$? Is it not just $$\int\frac{4}{x}dx=1$$

Comment: You can only pull the $y$ out of the integral when it is independent of $x$. You are probably used to $y=f(x)$, but this doesn't always hold, especially when integrating in higher dimensions.

Comment: thats the problem it is NOT true that we can only pull the $y$ when it is independent of $x$ in the double integral example we clearly we are just pulling out the $y$

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with
$$\int_J\left(\int_I 4yx^3 dx\right)dy=\int_J y\left(\int_I4x^3dx\right)dy$$
You just have to realize what this means. $\int_I f$ is defined for a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and some interval $I\subseteq\mathbb R$.

$\int_J\ldots dy$ just means that $f$ is the function given by $y\mapsto\ldots$

In our case we have an integral of a function given by $y\mapsto\int_I4yx^3dx$. Evaluating the function at $y$ we can write $\int_I4yx^3dx=y\int_I4x^3dx$, because we have to treat $y$ as a constant there.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes I agree in one case we are treating y as a constant and in the other case we are not yet the notation is identical I'm suggesting that the notation should reflect   when we are treating y as a constant