# Bringing out function of another variable (aside from integration variable) from integral

Tags: calculus, integration

When you have a constant value in your integral expression like $\int_xkxdx$ where *k* is constant you can bring the *k* out of the integral and write it as $k\int_xxdx$.
also when you have a variable like *v* where *v* is a function of *x* you can't simply pull the variable out of the integral like you did with the constant in the previous expression.
now my question is if I have a variable *v* and that *v* is function of some variable (like $v=2s$) apart from the integration variable (*x* here) can I pull that *v* out of the integral?

Comment: For clarity, it's better to add the integral to your question you will get more answers.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. As long as the value of the expression you're dealing with (e.g., a constant $k$ or $v = 2s$) is *not* changing (i.e., is at least effectively constant) as the integration variable, e.g., $x$, is changing over the range of the integral, you can pull that expression outside of the integration.

Comment: Think of it this way maybe: since $s$ doesn't depend on $x$, it's a constant as far as the $\int \dots dx$ is concerned. But then $v$ is a function of something that's constant, which means it itself is constant as far as the integral is concerned.

Comment: @user577215664 FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%20kxdx%20%3D%20k%5Cint%20xdx%24&p=1), I found the somewhat related questions of [Pulling out variables through the integral sign sometimes it's okay sometimes it's not okay](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/719082/602049) and [Independent and dependent variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2378892/602049).

Comment: @user577215664 it's not a specific integral. just a general question that came to my mind when solving some physics problems...

Comment: @GregMartin you're saying *s* is constant but i can't understand that. it's named variable for a reason. for example if my *s* is time, thus *v=2s* is a function of time. you can't say time is constant here. am i right?

Comment: @JohnOmielan well I think in terms of the dynamical problems I'm dealing with, my *s* is changing over the range of integral and thus I can't pull it out.

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean ......

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean